# Working with chemfig (and Benzene)

Tags: chemfig, syntax

I'm writing a paper about benzene derivatives, and I'd love to add them into my document using chemfig.

Can anyone either explain how I can create these or give me the code for the cementations below?

I allready found benzene online, but the others I can't seem to create:

```
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{=^[:-30]-[:30]=^[2]-[: 150]=^[:-150]-[6]}
```

I'd really appreciate it :)

[image: Needed Figures]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found out how it works...

```
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6(-=-=-=)}
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6(-=-=(-CH_3)-=)}
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6(-=-=(-([::-60]-OH)=[::60]O)-=)}
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6(-=-=(-OH)-=)}
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6(-=-=(-N^+([::-60]-O^{-})=[::60]O)-=)}
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6(-=-=(-NH_2)-=)}
```

[image: Benzene derivates]

Comment: The nitrogen in nitrobenzene is a bit off. You'll get an improved version with adding `|` between `N` and `^+`: `\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-N|^+([::-60]-O^{-})=[::60]O)-=)}`.  Personally I'd prefer another solution: `\chemfig{*6(-=-=(-\chemabove{N}{\scriptstyle+}([::-60]-O|^{-})=[::60]O)-=)}`.